# django using mptt and polymorphic for model

Tags: python, django

I have a PolymorphicMPTTModel and models are:

```
class AbstractCategory(PolymorphicMPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = PolymorphicTreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
                                       related_name='sub_categories')
class Category(AbstractCategory):
    def get_fields(self):
        pass 

class FakeCategory(AbstractCategory):
    def get_fields(self):
        pass
class AbstractProductModel(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProductModel(AbstractProductModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey('category.Category', related_name='product_models')

class FakeProductModel(AbstractProductModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey('category.AbstractCategory', related_name='fake_product_models')
```

Assume i have 3 objects of Category : Digital, Mobile-->Digital, Camera-->Digital.
Digital is parent of Mobile and Camera and this is simple example of tree structure.
I want to get all models that their category is Digital or sub category of Digital like Mobile or Camera. for that i'm using:

```
category = Category.objects.get(name='Digital')
descendants = category.get_descendants(include_self=True)
models = ProductModel.objects.filter(category__in=descendants).all()
```

I get this error:
**Cannot resolve keyword 'abstractcategory_ptr' into field. Choices are: category, ...**

and can't find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't quite understand why the `category__in` filter breaks (it should work!), you can implement this query in a much better way. When you join using the mptt fields, everything happens in a single query instead of a `WHERE x IN (SELECT ..)` subquery.

```
class ProductModelQuerySet(PolymorphicQuerySet):
    def get_descendants(self, category, include_self=False):
        # narrow one level deeper for include_self=False effect
        narrow = 0 if include_self else 1

        # MPTT optimization, no need for a subquery.
        return self.filter(
            category__tree_id=category.tree_id,
            category__lft__gte=category.lft + narrow,
            category__rght__lte=category.rght - narrow,
        )
```

and you can query that using:

```
models = ProductModel.objects.get_descendants(category)
```

Comment: with PolymorphicQuerySet i get this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
and chage it to PolymorphicManager i get:
'MultilingualPolymorphicQuerySet' object has no attribute 'tree_id'

Comment: that really makes me wonder how you initialize the manager and queryset. Somehow the manager code doesn't have a reference to the model - which is a completely different question alltogether

Comment: your first solution solved the problem. that was my fault. I really appreciate your help